# No documentation for CloudBackendActivity in android docs

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Following the steps in the tutorial for Cloud Endpoints but there is no documentation for CloudBackendActivity

At point 14:46 of the following video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew

turbomanage changes the FragmentActivity to CloudBackendActivity.

Also, shown here :

https://github.com/bradabrams/GeekSerendipity-io13/blob/master/AndroidClient/src/com/turbomanage/sample/geekwatch/GeekwatchActivity.java

However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation about CloudBackendActivity in developer.android.com nor any mention of what imports are necessary to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It turns out that CloudBackendActivity is not a framework class. It is implemented by turbomanage here :

https://github.com/bradabrams/GeekSerendipity-io13/blob/master/AndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/android/CloudBackendActivity.java